# updating multiple lists from a single dictionary entry using a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, variables

I have a list of keys (stored as strings: str1, str2, str3...) I would like to obtain from a dictionary. technically 100,000 dictionaries (Twitter tweets) I am streaming through using jsonlines.

I need the values for each key to be stored in separate value lists (each list is the name of a key) which i have already created as empy lists (ie list4str1, list4str2, list4str3...).

```
file = jsonlines.open(filename)
listofkeys = ['filter_level','created_at','favourite_count','retweet_count',(etc),]

tweet_texts = []
filter_level = []
created_at = [] 
favourite_count = [] 
retweet_count = []

for tweet in file 
    if tweet["text"] not in duplication_check:
        #What happens when a unique tweet is found 
        iteration += 1
        string = ("Tweet: " + str(iteration) + " :" + tweet["text"])
        duplication_check.append(tweet["text"])
        tweet_texts.append(string)
        uniquecount += 1

#_______THIS IS THE BIT I NEED HELP WITH______
        for items in listofkeys
            items.append(tweet[items])
#_______THIS IS THE BIT I NEED HELP WITH______

        if iteration%10000 == True & iteration != 1:
            print(iteration, " Items")
    else:
        #What happens when a copy is found
        copycount += 1
        iteration += 1 
        if iteration%10000 == True:
            print(itteration-1, " Items")
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I have no idea how this would work using my limited coding knowledge thus require assistance (perhaps there is a library or niche function?)

Comment: I suspect that duplication_check, which you didn't include in the code here, is a string and not a list. Also, start with the line that's throwing an error and look at that line and the one above it. I also don't see where you establish what "itteration" starts at.

Comment: Sorry yes I have only posted half the code- duplication check is a list and iteration is simply the number of tweets currently processed- I use it as a progress tracker for long runtimes

Comment: For future reference for anyone viewing this - the code works perfectly apart from the error listed at the bottom - this is my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess since there seems to be a few things missing from the code you posted

```
 for items in listofkeys
            items.append(tweet[items])
```

`items` is a String in `listofkeys` you cant append anything to a string like this

A good solution would be to create a dictionary of lists using the items string as the key.

```
final_results = {}
for items in listofkeys
    if items not in final_results: 
        final_results[items] = [tweet[items]]
    else:
        final_results[items].append(tweet[items])
```

Comment: Sadly that’s what I was thinking - I suppose what I should have asked is ‘is there a way to convert string to variable to allow this code to work’

Comment: @JamesHulse create a dictionary of lists using the items as the keys.

Editing Answer with new suggestion